# xyz is not within bounds of type-variable T

Tags: java, generics, type-variables

I have the following class:

```
public class Blub extends AbstractPreloadDefinition<AddressmasterModel>
```

The javac compiler gives me the following error:

> Error:(15, 79) java: type argument AddressmasterModel is not within
>   bounds of type-variable T

`AbstractPreloadDefinition` looks as follows:

```
abstract class AbstractPreloadDefinition<T extends PersistedEntity<?>> implements PreloadDefinition<T>
```

and `AddressmasterModel` looks as follows:

```
public abstract class AddressmasterModel<V extends VoucherModel> implements Serializable, Auditable, PersistedEntity<Integer>, Comparable<AddressmasterModel<V>>
```

So, `AddressmasterModel` implements `PersistedEntity`. Where's the error? I can't find it :/

I'm using **IntelliJ 2017.1** and **javac** as compiler. If I switch to **eclipse** as compiler, this error is gone...

Comment: Please add the definition of VoucherModel. Better yet, create an MCVE

Comment: What about `PreloadDefinition`?

Comment: After automatically resolving the compile errors of missing classes, I got this **warning**: *`AddressmasterModel` is a raw type. References to generic type `AddressmasterModel<V>` should be parameterized.*. You can fix this warning like @d-m suggested. Otherwise, please create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to extend `PersistedEntity<Something>` and not `PersistedEntity`.  This works:

```
class Blub extends AbstractPreloadDefinition<AddressmasterModel<VoucherModel>>
```